# buffergeometry instancing dynamic How to Update position

Tags: three.js

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic and https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things

The Example Spins the Cubes around.

I want to be able to change there postion. The documention says to do this
    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true; and update the position data. But When I do that nothing happens

Any Idea?

Comment: Solved. adding only this to the animate will update the postion by chanigng the offset mesh.geometry.attributes.offset.array[0] += .25;
    mesh.geometry.attributes.offset.needsUpdate = true;

Answer (score 0):

Solved. adding only this to the animate will update the postion by chanigng the offset mesh.geometry.attributes.offset.array[0] += .25; mesh.geometry.attributes.offset.needsUpdate = true;